# Clarifications during the Angular Build process

Tags: angular-cli

I am recently approaching the angular framework but I can't understand one thing I hope someone can help me to clarify this concept better;

So when I launch the classic "ng build" command to generate the build of my project, a folder called "build /dist/public" is created inside there are some files but my main concept is this:

in the **Index.html** file that is generated inside he writes this field:
`<script src="main.aaedba49815d2ab0.js">`
briefly, I would like this line to be written like this:
 `<script src="my-name-folder/main.aaedba49815d2ab0.js">`

do you think it is possible to do such a thing?

P.s this question was written via googleTranslate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this using the `ng build`.

```
ng build --base-href /my-name-folder/
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer I solved it and I was able to better understand the tag you wrote to me very kind